# Obtener valores con like mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito hacer una query que me devuelva un solo resultado, se trata de lo siguiente: entre mis registros tengo un campo llamado nombre y quiero que la query me devuelva el nombre que contenga cumla con lo siguiente:

- Si doy "hola" y en los registros tengo: "gato" "holas" y "perro" me debe devolver "holas" , sin embargo quiero limitarlo a que solo tenga hasta 2 caracteres diferente, es decir si tengo "holassssss" o "aaaaahola" no aplicarían, pero si tengo "holass" o "aahola" entonces sí
- Si hay más de un resultado entonces devolver el que tenga menos caracteres diferentes, es decir si los registros que conciden son "holass", "holas" y "hola" entonces debe devolver "hola"
- Se debe ignorar si es mayusculas o minusculas

intenté usando :

```
SELECT NOMBRE FROM USUARIO WHERE NOMBRE LIKE '%__hola__%';
```

Pero como notarán no logra lo esperado, espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me parece que lo más sencillo sería usar `LENGTH`:

```
SELECT NOMBRE
FROM USUARIO
WHERE NOMBRE LIKE '%hola%'
AND LENGTH(NOMBRE) <= LENGTH('Hola') + 2
ORDER BY LENGTH(NOMBRE) 
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar usando REGEXP que permite mas opciones para parsear un resultado que lo que podrias obtener con LIKE.
Un ejemplo:

```
SELECT NOMBRE FROM USUARIO WHERE REGEXP 'hola' LIMIT 1;
```

Sugiero revises las opciones disponibles con REGEXP y elijas la que mejor se ajuste a la busqueda que estas realizando.